# How are some variables injected to application.yml in spring boot when it is started

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an spring boot-1.4.1.RELEASE application 
Another application is depended to my application and it have more variables than my application.yml's variables and it want to inject this variables to my application.yml when it is started.
How does it do?
Is it possible?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41038491/613628) help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Cloud Config Server for that purpose. Here is a good tutorial:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html